# Visual force page redirection from lightning community

Tags: lightning-community

I have lightning community configured with lightning component. In that component there is a button called 'redirectToResponse'.

This button is redirecting to visual force page with "https://CommunityURL/siteprefix/s/apex/avTestMyPage?Id=a0P1J00000YUjs6UAD&retURL=%2Fhome%2Fhome.jsp" URL.

So when user click on that button it shows "Invalid Page" page error.

Is there any way we can redirect to visual force page with URL from lightning component in lightning community?

Answer (score 0):

call visualforce page from lightning component like this

```
<a href="/apex/avTestMyPage" style="width:100px; text-decoration: none; padding: 1% 6%;" target="_blank">{!$Label.buttonlabel}</a>
```

this will work same as button just give css accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Go to Setup -> Communities -> All Communities -> click Manage -> Administration -> Pages -> Go to force.com -> Click on public access settings.

This shows you a profile page that has visualforce pages with public access. If you removed your page from there it will be only available in authenticated context.